# JSON decoded cast to integer but not giving expected result

Tags: php

I am decoding JSON from a webservice like this, for the $rspcode i am casting to integer and checking in a switch statement if response is 00(which is an integer). Please what I am doing wrong as I am not getting the desired output;

```
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); //done
$decoder = json_decode($response);
$rspcode        = $decoder->{'ResponseCode'};
$rspamount      = $decoder->{'Amount'};
$rspcardno      = $decoder->{'CardNumber'};
$rspmerchant    = $decoder->{'MerchantReference'};
$rsppayref      = $decoder->{'PaymentReference'};
$rsprefnumber   = $decoder->{'RetrievalReferenceNumber'};
$rsptransdate   = $decoder->{'TransactionDate'};
$rspdescription = $decoder->{'ResponseDescription'};



 switch(intval($rspcode))
    {
        case "00":
    //do something
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
```

Comment: `00` is not an integer. `0` is.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that is the value the service is returning and they expect it to be treated as int.Don't know why

Comment: Well you're using `intval` and then `case`ing it against a string. Do you really think that will work?

Answer (score 0):

`intval('00')` would be 0, not 00. You could also improve your case but not making it a string , but since switch uses loose comparison `0` and `"0"` would still technically work